# Redirection from component to view in joomla 2.5.8

Tags: redirect, joomla

I am new to joomla. am using joomla 2.5.8 version. i have created one component. i can post form data from view to task in component. but i couldn't redirect from task to view. this is my simple function in controller. This URL is saved in Redirect manager.

```
  function sample(){

        $mainframes = JFactory::getApplication();
        $link=  JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_new',FALSE);
        $msg = JText::_('welcome');

        $mainframes->redirect($link,$msg);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. What if you just redirect to the home page: `JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(JRoute::_(JURI::base()));`. Does that at least work?

Comment: usually you don't invoke redirect directly, rather set its values and let Joomla handle it: $mainframes->setRedirect($link,$msg) should work.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me in my component's custom task, `release()`:

```
# Get iop_id from query string
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$iop_id = $app->input->get('id');

$url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_iop&task=plan.edit&id=' . (int)$iop_id, false);
$app->redirect($url);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$id = JRequest::getVar('id');
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

$url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_iop&task=plan.edit&id=' . (int)$id);
$app->redirect($url);
```

Comment: Apart from combining two lines, you basically copied my entire answer. Thanks.